# jquery for External List works for the first page

Tags: 2013, jquery

My jquery is in PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead at the AllItems for the List. My list is external list. 
When I go to the list. Everythings ok. But when I go to the next page it doesn't work.
How can I solve it?

Her is my jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {alert(1);
        $('table[summary="CalisanBilgi"] tr').find('.ms-vb-lastCell').each(function(){
           $(this).html('<img src="http://ahapp/img/image.aspx?s=' + $(this).html() + '"/>') ;       
       });         
    }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try putting the jQuery code inside a Content Query Web Part on that page?

Usually it is better practice to put the Javascript inside a Text file somewhere in your root site's library, and then reference it from the CQWP. Editing the page head itself will not always work.

Comment: It worked. I just forgot to <script> tag  for js-min link